# Swift Convert date string to Date

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I got a date string from server side, which is `Tue, 28 May 2019 13:24:06 +0000`. I tried to do following:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "Tue, 28 May 2019 13:24:06 +0000")
```

result is **`nil`**

How can I convert a string like this to a `Date`?

Comment: You probably need to specify a custom date/time format

Comment: You may also want to look at https://www.nsdateformatter.com for reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a specific `dateFormat`. And when doing so, set the date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "Tue, 28 May 2019 13:24:06 +0000")
```

See the documentation for `dateFormat` for links that take you a full description of what all of the format specifiers mean.

Keep in mind that when converting a Date to a String for display to the user, then using date and time styles is the best solution. But for parsing a String into a Date, use `dateFormat`.

Comment: It worked, even without specifying `local`. Thanks.   Is there any generic approach to parse any type of date string? Let's say, user add a new rss feed which I couldn't know the type of date string from this new feed in advance

Comment: You need to specify this special locale, otherwise your code will fail for many users, especially if their device is setup for a non-English language.

Comment: Look into `NSDataDetector` as a possible way to handle strings with unknown date formats.

Comment: All right. I will look into `NSDataDetector `, and specify locale in my code. Thanks again!